# Mysql Tomcat 6 Connection refused

Tags: mysql, tomcat6

I have a tomcat app running on a ubuntu cloud server. Everything was working well until a few hours ago. I tried to add a second tomcat app with a similar data source resource in the context.xml. The idea was that the first app would connect to the first DB and the second to the second Database. I called the datasources the same name. It didnt work.

Now I have removed the second app and I cant connect to the database from the original app. All with the same context.xml as it was before I started today. This is driving me crazy.

I get this exception.

`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Server connection failure during transaction. Due to underlying exception: 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused'.`

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: What have you tried? If you have ssh access to the server, try to log in to the server and check from command line if the database is reachable. Sounds like it has actually been stopped or something.

Comment: Yes I can connect to the DB at the console using ssh and the creds that the context is using

Comment: Does anyone know how I can get more information from logs in mysql to see whats going on? I granted access tot he user @ localhost and @ 127.0.0.1. Still same error. This is bizarre as it was working a few hours ago.

Comment: So I added the ip address of cloud server to the Datasource DB url and now it works. Dont know why .... Tomcat + mysql are on the same machine. leaving it as jdbc:mysql:///MY_DB?autoReconnect=true should be ok